# Sed out matching the partial string from a full string in linux

Tags: python, linux, awk, sed

1. I have a full string as given below

   ```
   "^aloha_lang.maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
   ```
2. And I have partial string to search to match

   ```
   "maui_.*_rams"
   ```
3. And if that partial string matches the full string, I wanted to sed out all the string until the matching string. For eg. the output wanted is

   ```
   "^maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
   ```

Tried like this and other ways, buts its not sed'ing out correctly:

```
echo "^aloha_lang.maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$" | sed 's/^[^maui_.*_rams]*//;p'
```

Any simple oneliner or basic step that I am missing ? Or a regular expression way in python

Comment: Not clear because `maui_.*_rams` will only match between `maui` and `rams` so how are you expecting `.blue.lagoon$` also in output?

Comment: 1. At maui_island_A_rams place there could be other strings as well like maui_island_B_rams or etc. 
2. So to match if that string exists in the full string I use this partial string maui_.*_rams.
3. Once the match is done, I wanted to sed out all the things that is there till the matching partial string. In this case its maui_.*_rams. So wanted to that same partial string for SED'ing as well.

Comment: What are the `"`, `^` and `$` in your sample string 1? Your "tried like this" code is operating on a different string that does not contain any `"` and your sample string 3 starts with `"^` which does not correspond to the requirement "sed out all the string until the matching string". The sample string 2 (even if treated as a regex) can never match since neither `"m` nor `s"` appear in sample 1.

Comment: Your example isn't adequate to test a potential solution. You should have lines that match the start but not the end of the regexp, lines that match each of them multiple times on a line, lines that don't match at all, lines that have to match regexp metachars, etc. It's always much easier to match the strings you want than it is to not match similar strings you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming those are literal `^` and `$` characters:

```
$ echo "^aloha_lang.maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$" | sed -E 's/^\^(.*)(maui_.*_rams.*)/^\2/'
^maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support; also allows for defining capture groups without having to escape the parens
- `^\^` - input starts with a literal `^`
- `(.*)` - 1st capture group consists of all characters up to the ...
- `(maui_.*_rams.*)` - 2nd capture group which matches everything from `maui_.*_rams` to the end of the input
- `^\2` - replacement is a literal `^` plus the full contents of the 2nd capture group

Comment: no point having the leading `.*` in a capture group since you're not printing it.

Answer (score 2):

After declaring the string in the shell:

```
$ str='"^aloha_lang.maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"'
```

Then:

With sed:

```
$ echo "$str" | sed -n 's/maui_.*_rams/\n&/; s/.*\n//p'
maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
```

With awk:

```
$ echo "$str" | awk '(i=match($0,/maui_.*_rams/)) && $0=substr($0,i)'
maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
```

With gawk:

```
$ echo "$str" | gawk -v RS='maui_.*_rams[^\n]*' '$0=RT'
maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
```

With bash's `=~` regex comparison which stores results in `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
$ [[ $str =~ maui.*_rams.* ]]
$ echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
```

With a grep that has `-o` option:

```
$ echo "$str" | grep -o 'maui_.*_rams.*'
maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon$"
```

Comment: If required, it is trivial to prepend `"^` to the output in all versions

Comment: Note that my `sed` version differs from other people's in the case that `maui_` appears more than once: my code keeps the longer match, others keep the shorter.

Comment: Thanks @jhnc .. Only way that is left out is to try out in Python as well. Looks like you have given most of the options.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, if the current input line matches the `/maui_.*_rams/` pattern, you want to strip everything that comes before "maui_" and print the remainder.

```
echo 'aloha_lang.maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon' \
| sed -ne '/maui_.*_rams/s/^.*\(maui_\)/\1/p'
```

produces :

```
maui_island_A_rams.blue.lagoon
```

##### *Edit*:

For a shorter SED expression, you can also skip the matching test and simply keep the substitution statement as suggested by @jhnc : `sed -ne 's/^.*\(maui_\)/\1/p'`

Hope that helps.

Comment: you can avoid some duplication: `sed -ne 's/.*\(maui_.*_rams\)/\1/p'`